# How to get dimensions of WrapPanel defined in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wrappanel

I have `WrapPanel` defined in XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
            <WrapPanel x:Name="VideoPanel" >
  </WrapPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

And then when I access the size of that `WrapPanel` in `.cs`

```
  Console.WriteLine(VideoPanel.ActualWidth + " x " + VideoPanel.ActualHeight);
        Console.WriteLine(VideoPanel.Width + " x " + VideoPanel.Height);
```

I get the output:

```
   0 x 0
0 x 0
is not a number x is not a number
```

**How to get actual size?**

Full XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="HomeSecurity.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HomeSecurity" 
        Title="MainWindow" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="9*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
            <WrapPanel x:Name="VideoPanel" >


            </WrapPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Full code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {


        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            createGUI();
        }

        private void createGUI() {
            AddVideoStream("192.168.0.3");
        }

        private void AddVideoStream(String sourceIP) {

            Console.WriteLine(VideoPanel.ActualWidth + " x " + VideoPanel.ActualHeight);
            Console.WriteLine(VideoPanel.Width + " x " + VideoPanel.Height);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `ActualWidth` / `ActualHeight`?

Comment: @dkozl Please look at edit.

Comment: When are you getting this size? Is it, by any chance, in constructor?

Comment: @dkozl Full code: http://wklej.org/id/1228926/

Comment: So yes, in constructor. Try calling `createGUI` in `Window.Loaded` event

Comment: removed msg -not relevent

Comment: @dkozl how the to override or add Window.Loaded? Could you post it as answer?

Comment: `<Window x:Class="HomeSecurity.MainWindow" ... Loaded="Window_Loaded">` and in code `private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { ... }`

Comment: @dkozl so I should createGUI in that method?

Comment: Call `createGUI` in `Window_Loaded` instead of constructor and see if it helps

Comment: @dkozl It helped. Is it an orthodoxic way to insert something in the `Window` by c#?

Comment: @dkozl If you want post it as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get actual size you should use `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties of `FrameworkElement` but instead of getting them in constructor use [`FrameworkElement.Loaded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

```
<Window x:Class="HomeSecurity.MainWindow" ... Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

and in code

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
   createGUI();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition x:Name="Row"  Height="9*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Column" Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition  Width="8*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <!--Used for calculating height and width-->
    <Grid x:Name="Dimesiongrid" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></Grid>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
        <WrapPanel x:Name="VideoPanel" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

and behind code

```
    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VideoPanel.Height = Dimesiongrid.ActualHeight;
        VideoPanel.Width = Dimesiongrid.ActualWidth;
    }
```

this height and width you can use for calculation